# Can't make a simple UI Test with doubleTap() work (macOS)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitest

I have this simple `ContentView` on a Mac App project :

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            CustomView()
                .frame(minWidth: 150, idealWidth: 150, maxWidth: 150, minHeight: 100, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 100, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .accessibility(identifier: "touch1")
                .onTapGesture(count: 2){
                    isPresented = true
                }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            let alert = Alert(title: Text("Double Clicked"))
            return alert
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image(systemName: "cursorarrow.click.2")
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to write a UI Test for it :

```swift
    func testExample() throws {
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        XCTAssert(app.images["touch1"].isHittable)
        
        app.images["touch1"].doubleTap()

        // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
        
        XCTAssertTrue(app.alerts["Double Clicked"].waitForExistence(timeout: 1))
    }
```

When I run the test, the alert doesn't display, but the mouse cursor moves over in the middle of my button, which makes me think `app.images["touch1"]` is valid.

[image]

Anyone using `doubleTap()` ? How can I UI test my app without it ?

Complete log below :

```
2021-03-15 15:09:16.836806+0100 DoubleClickUITests-Runner[4333:80088] Running tests...
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2021-03-15 15:09:17.019
Test Suite 'DoubleClickUITests.xctest' started at 2021-03-15 15:09:17.020
Test Suite 'DoubleClickUITests' started at 2021-03-15 15:09:17.021
Test Case '-[DoubleClickUITests.DoubleClickUITests testExample]' started.
    t =     0.00s Start Test at 2021-03-15 15:09:17.025
    t =     0.43s Set Up
2021-03-15 15:09:17.567336+0100 DoubleClickUITests-Runner[4333:80593] [Arbitration] starting DTServiceHub child handshake.0 (send: 0x5d03, receive: 0x5c3f)
2021-03-15 15:09:17.567677+0100 DoubleClickUITests-Runner[4333:80088] [Arbitration] attempting connection to singleton: 2568 with send port: 0x5e03
2021-03-15 15:09:17.568590+0100 DoubleClickUITests-Runner[4333:80088] [Arbitration] handshake SUCCESSFUL (child: 4335 -> singleton: 2568)
    t =     0.55s Open org.tynsoe.DoubleClick
    t =     0.72s     Launch org.tynsoe.DoubleClick
    t =     2.52s         Wait for accessibility to load
    t =     2.96s         Setting up automation session
    t =     2.99s         Wait for org.tynsoe.DoubleClick to idle
    t =     3.18s Find the "touch1" Image
    t =     3.39s Double tap "touch1" Image
    t =     3.39s     Wait for org.tynsoe.DoubleClick to idle
    t =     3.54s     Find the "touch1" Image
    t =     3.73s     Synthesize event
    t =     4.60s     Wait for org.tynsoe.DoubleClick to idle
    t =     4.76s Waiting 1.0s for "Double Clicked" Alert to exist
    t =     5.76s     Checking `Expect predicate `exists == 1` for object "Double Clicked" Alert`
    t =     5.76s         Checking existence of `"Double Clicked" Alert`
    t =     5.87s         Capturing element debug description
    t =     5.87s Checking existence of `"Double Clicked" Alert`
/Users/yann/Desktop/DoubleClick/DoubleClickUITests/DoubleClickUITests.swift:36: error: -[DoubleClickUITests.DoubleClickUITests testExample] : XCTAssertTrue failed
    t =     6.14s Tear Down
Test Case '-[DoubleClickUITests.DoubleClickUITests testExample]' failed (6.346 seconds).
Test Suite 'DoubleClickUITests' failed at 2021-03-15 15:09:23.368.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 6.346 (6.347) seconds
Test Suite 'DoubleClickUITests.xctest' failed at 2021-03-15 15:09:23.369.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 6.346 (6.348) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' failed at 2021-03-15 15:09:23.369.
     Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 6.346 (6.350) seconds
```

Comment: I have run the test and everything works as expected.

Comment: Now that's interesting.
So when running testExample() SwiftUI Test target, the application launches, moves the cursor over the image, and double click on it, then it displays the alert?
I'm just double checking that you're talking about the UI test and not the app itself, the app works as expected but that's not the point, it's really about UI Test. I'm running Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the tests: the app launches, the alert gets displayed, both assertions pass.

Comment: Can you share your Xcode and OS version ?

Comment: macOS: BigSur 11.2.2 (20D80) / Xcode 12.4 (12D4e) / Intel processor

Comment: Thanks. Running 11.2.1 and can't upgrade without corporate release of 11.2.2. I had a friend running the code and had the same issue I have, so that's really weird. I'm adding a GIF showing the issue

Comment: I don’t think it’s Xcode. I am running the test on iPhone simulator while you are using your Mac as test target.

Comment: I don't understand, it's a mac app. Did you change it to an iPhone app ? EDIT. Ah I see I didn't share the whole project, just the code

Comment: In that case maybe you should replace `doubleTap()` with `doubleClick()`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It has the same effect.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm following a tutorial from Ray Wenderlichs SwiftUI book. The app works as expected, but the UI tests doesn't. I see double tap / click in the console. Really odd.